# Surprising behavior of document.write

Tags: javascript, document.write

On my page I am writing an external JS and an iframe using document.write like below

```
document.write("<sc" + "ript src=\"http://d2hzts1b0z7hqh.cloudfront.net/arb.js\"></script>");
document.write("<iframe id='mytestframe'></iframe>");
document.close();
var frame = document.getElementById("mytestframe");
console.log(frame);
```

The value of frame printed by the last console.log statement is 'null'. But if I comment out the first line `document.write("<sc" + "ript src=\"http://d2hzts1b0z7hqh.cloudfront.net/arb.js\"></sc" + "ript>");` the log statement prints a node instance.

Can someone please explain the reason behind this surprising behavior.

You can play around with the JSFiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/yqLdy1k1/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are calling *getElementById* too early, delay it until the load event occurs or put it in a different script element below the one calling *document.write*.

The following works fine for me:

```
document.write('Hello World');
document.write('<script src="http://d2hzts1b0z7hqh.cloudfront.net/arb.js"><\/script>');
document.write('<iframe id="mytestframe"><\/iframe>');
document.close();

// Delay looking for iframe until page is loaded
window.onload = function() {
  var frame = document.getElementById("mytestframe");
  console.log(frame);
};
```

Note that you need to quote the "/" in all closing tags within script elements, so `<\/` on all of them (e.g. `<\/iframe>`), not just `<\/script>`.

Comment: I am wondering why window onload will get triggered. Is it because I am modifying the DOM ?

Comment: You should be calling this during the page load, not after. Calling *document.write* after the load event has occurred will first call *document.open* and clear the **entire** content of the document (see [*MDN: document.write*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/write).

Comment: But how it always works without document.write('<script src="http://d2hzts1b0z7hqh.cloudfront.net/arb.js"><\/script>'); Isn't in that case also it should throw null ?

Comment: It depends on how long it takes to create the element, iframes have a fair bit of overhead.

Answer (score 1):

Here is my theory:
When you add a Script tag with src, browser will load the js file first, and then continue parse following HTML tags. Otherwise, it will parse them immediately.
Here is my testing code. Only tested with Firefox.
HTML file t1.htm:

```
<html >
<head>

</head>
<body >
    <script >
        console.log("start");
        document.write("Hello World");
        document.write("<style src='t1.css' ><\/style>");//external css file, works fine
        document.write("<input id='ibefore' />");//element added before external js file, works
        document.write('<script src=\"\"><\/script>');//with a src, null
        document.write('<script ><\/script>');//without a valid src, works
        document.write("<img src='t1.jpg' ><\/img>");//external img, works
        document.write('<script src="http://d2hzts1b0z7hqh.cloudfront.net/arb.js"  defer><\/script>');//defer, works
        document.write('<script src="http://d2hzts1b0z7hqh.cloudfront.net/arb.js" async><\/script>');//async works
        console.log("before write script");
        document.write("<script src='t1.js' ><\/script>");//external js, be load and executed after this script tag
        console.log("after write script");
        document.write("<iframe id='mytestframe'>test</iframe>");//add the iframe
        console.log("after write iframe");
        document.close();
        console.log("before get iframe");
        var frame = document.getElementById("mytestframe");
        var ib = document.getElementById('ibefore');
        console.log(frame);
        console.log('input ibefore');
        console.log(ib);
        console.log('end of script');
    </script>
    <script>
        console.log('after script page.');
        console.log(document.getElementById("mytestframe"));
    </script>
    <input type="button" value="call"  />
    <script>
        console.log('End of source page.');
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

External js file t1.js:

```
console.log("in writed script");
console.log(document.getElementById("mytestframe"));
```